# Can an Android AsyncTask doInBackground be synchronized to serialize the task execution?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-asynctask

Is it possible to make `AsyncTask.doInBackground` synchronized - or achieve the same result in another way?

```java
class SynchronizedTask extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected synchronized Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // do something that needs to be completed 
        // before another doInBackground can be called
    }
}
```

In my case, any `AsyncTask.execute()` can be started before a previous one has completed, but I need to execute the code in `doInBackground` only after the previous task has finished.

**EDIT**: As correctly pointed out, the synchronization works only on the same object instance.
Unfortunately, it is not possible to create an `AsyncTask` and call `execute()` more than once on the same object instance, as specified in the "Threading rules" section of the `AsyncTask` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

The solution is to use a custom [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) to serialize the tasks, or, if you use API 11 or above, [`AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29), as suggested in the comments below.

I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893813/can-an-android-asynctask-doinbackground-be-synchronized-to-serialize-the-task-ex#9906890) showing an implementation of a `SerialExecutor` that can be used to queue tasks that will be executed sequentially.

Comment: That's not what synchronized means! It means that the function (or the block) is executed without interleaving with another thread on this object.

Comment: @Bondax Yes, I know. But `doInBackground` can be called by different background threads, as per documentation. Since the UI thread can call `new SynchronizedTask()` at any time before a previous one has finished, you can have two or more different interleaving threads executing `doInBackground` at the same time.

Comment: Yes, but on different AsyncTask instances!

Comment: If you use API level 11, you can create [SingleThreadExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) and start you AsyncTask by calling [AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which resulting a queuing AsyncTask execution.

Comment: @yorkw Many thanks for the input, this is exactly what I need. However, I am targeting APIs below level 11, so I think I need to implement myself a custom `Executor` which will be used by each Activity to serialize the task execution.

Comment: @LorenzoPolidori, Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211684/asynctask-executeonexecutor-before-api-level-11) too see how to port executeOnExecutor() under API Level 11. In addition, worth to check out [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911333/queing-multiple-async-tasks-in-android-1-6/7911399#7911399) as well.

Comment: @Bondax  If the `doInBackgournd()` method in different `AysncTask` instance objects read and write some same variables. This could make error. So I think to synchronize the AysncTask instance object is necessary.

Comment: @yorkw If the target devices' OS is `Froyo`, can it support `SingleThreadExecutor`?

Comment: @Stallman, yes, this API is there since API Level 1, check out [Excutors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

Comment: @yorkw  Thanks to the second question. What I mean in the first question is that I only want `one thread` running the task(extends `AysncTask`) and that's what it currently does. But for older version API and OS, the `asyncTask` run on concurrently.(http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html)  Should I add `synchronize` or manage the execution of the thread or just `do something` to prevent the callers call the task concurrently? Thanks.

Comment: @Stallman: The async task should only be executed by one thread at all. Don't call doInBackground() manually. Only global variables can be accessed in a critical way, so make sure the access to these variables is thread safe. 'Synchronized' means: No two threads can execute that method on that object instance. Hence and again: dont call doInBackground() manually!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use [`AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) with a `SERIAL_EXECUTOR`, but this is only available for API level 11 or above:

```java
new AsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, params);
```

To target the Android APIs below level 11, I ended up implementing a custom class which encapsulates an [`ExecutorService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with a thread pool size of 1. The full code is open-sourced [here](https://bitbucket.org/lorenzopolidori/serialexecutor/src).

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)` creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most `nThreads` threads will be active processing tasks. In my case, `nThreads` is 1, which means tasks can be queued, but only one task will be executed at any given time.

Here is the code:

```java
public abstract class SerialExecutor {
    private final ExecutorService mExecutorService;

    public SerialExecutor() {
        mExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    }

    public void queue(Context context, TaskParams params) {
        mExecutorService.submit(new SerialTask(context, params));
    }

    public void stop() {
        mExecutorService.shutdown();
    }

    public abstract void execute(TaskParams params);

    public static abstract class TaskParams { }

    private class SerialTask implements Runnable {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final TaskParams mParams;

        public SerialTask(Context context, TaskParams params) {
            mContext = context;
            mParams = params;
        }

        public void run() {
            execute(mParams);
            Activity a = (Activity) mContext;
            a.runOnUiThread(new OnPostExecute());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to notify the UI thread
     */
    private class OnPostExecute implements Runnable {

        public void run() {

        }
    }
}
```

This can be extended and used as a serial task executor in an `Activity`:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MySerialExecutor mSerialExecutor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        mSerialExecutor = new MySerialExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mSerialExecutor != null) {
            mSerialExecutor.stop();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onTrigger(int param) {
        mSerialExecutor.queue(this, new MySerialExecutor.MyParams(param));
    }

    private static class MySerialExecutor extends SerialExecutor {

        public MySerialExecutor() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(TaskParams params) {
            MyParams myParams = (MyParams) params;
            // do something...
        }

        public static class MyParams extends TaskParams {
            // ... params definition

            public MyParams(int param) {
                // ... params init
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is SERIAL_EXECUTOR in                                          new syncTask().executeOnExecutor(SERIAL_EXECUTOR, params); param is my parameter....

Comment: May an IntentService be a valid option? It runs the jobs asynchronously and implements a FIFO job queue.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to think about using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) instead. It seems like it may be a better fit for your process since it has built in features for queuing.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the good alternative, but I need to have a serial task execution which is carried out independently by each resumed Activity. This is why I need a per-Activity background task serializer similar to `AsyncTask` rather than a central service to be shared among all the Activities.

Comment: I think what will give you similar results to executeOnExecuter as you just noted in this question is calling a Static Syncronized Method in a class from the AsyncTask(this will lock the class out from other threads) that contains your work to process. This however along with executeOnExecutor will not insure the order of your threads being processed. If you feel that you are comfortable with the way in which you are threading with API 11's executeOnExecutor then use this process if not you should queue your threads.

Comment: To make sure the order of the tasks is preserved, I have implemented a `SerialExecutor` class which uses an `ExecutorService` created by `Executors#newFixedThreadPool(1)` (see my answer to this question). From the documentation of `Executors#newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)`, this method creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. At any point, at most `nThreads` threads will be active processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available.

Comment: Your answer looks like it should definitely work. Sorry I just woke up when I wrote that. Also to better answer your comment. You could just bind the IntentService to any given Activity. That should also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RestAsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback;
    private Context context;
    private String method;
    private static final AtomicInteger PROGRESS_NUM = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private static ProgressDialog PROGRESS_DIALOG;

    public RestAsyncTask1(Context context, AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback, String method) {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.context = context;
        this.method = method;
    }

    public static String format(String url, String... params) {
        String[] encoded = new String[params.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            encoded[i] = Uri.encode(params[i]);
        }

        return String.format(url, (String[]) encoded);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        int x = PROGRESS_NUM.getAndIncrement();

        if (x == 0) {
            String title = "M_yug";
            PROGRESS_DIALOG = new ProgressDialog(context);
           // PROGRESS_DIALOG.setTitle(title);
            PROGRESS_DIALOG.setIndeterminate(true);
            PROGRESS_DIALOG.setCancelable(false);
            PROGRESS_DIALOG.setOnCancelListener(null);
            PROGRESS_DIALOG.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            PROGRESS_DIALOG.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = params[0];
        String response = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        if (params.length > 1) {
            if (method.equals(Method.GET)) {
                url = format(url, (String[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(params, 1, params.length));
            } else if (params.length > 2) {
                url = format(url, (String[]) Arrays.copyOfRange(params, 1, params.length - 1));
            }

            try {
                URL call = new URL(url);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) call.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                //connection.setRequestProperty("M-Yug", Utilities.VERSION);
                connection.setRequestMethod(method);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                if (method.equals("POST")) {
                    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                    outputStream.write(params[params.length - 1].getBytes());
                    outputStream.flush();
                }

                int status = connection.getResponseCode();

                if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                    response = readValue(is);
                } else if (status == 400) {
                    InputStream is = connection.getErrorStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }

                    reader.close();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "" + builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                connection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        int x = PROGRESS_NUM.decrementAndGet();

        if (x == 0 && PROGRESS_DIALOG != null && PROGRESS_DIALOG.isShowing()) {
            PROGRESS_DIALOG.dismiss();
        }

        if (s!=null) {
            String resopnse=s.toString();
            callback.onSuccess(resopnse);
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(context,"Server Not Responding",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private String readValue(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    enum Method {
        GET, POST
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

AsyncTask is used to run a background thread so that you current process is not interupted .

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

where first of all your doInBackground function iscalled and the returned object will move to on post execute.
which line of code you want to run after some process you can put that in PostExecute function.
this will surely help you