# The spinner menu shows very long text, but not the triangle image

Tags: android, spinner

When I make the spinner with very long text, the spinner button (not drop down menu), which usually shows the selected text and the triangle image(▼), doesn't show the triangle image.
I tested with normal (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item) layout and multiline layout.
But neither did.

The right side of spinner button is the outside of the window. 
(Sorry, I can't attach the image because I'm a new user.)

The sources are following;

SpinnerTestActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class SpinnerTestActivity extends Activity {
String[] mStrings = {"verrrrrrrrrry looooooooooooooong",
        "abc loooooooooooooooooooooooooong",
        "xyz"
};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
//       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mStrings);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.multiline_spinner_item, mStrings);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

multiline_spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you defined the `android:prompt` attribute in your Android `Spinner` controller?

It will help you. Please see the following code:

```
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/planet_prompt"
/>
```

You can refer to the following link: [Can an Android AsyncTask doInBackground be synchronized to serialize the task execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893813/can-an-android-asynctask-doinbackground-be-synchronized)

Comment: My poor english caused misunderstanding. So I modified my question. My question is about a spinner button, not a drop menu of spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your observations on my question.

I found the answer.

add

```
spinner.getLayoutParams().width = spinner.getWidth();
```

after

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```